# Psychopy TextStim Bounding Box

Tags: psychopy

Is it possible to control the width of a bounding box for a text stim? I know the parameter is read only but it adjusts to changes in the size of the text or the length of a word. I'd like to display some text across one line at a large size but it always spreads it out over two lines. If I add the underscore it fits on the screen but I replace the _ with a space and it goes back to two lines.

```
>>> from psychopy import visual  
>>> win=visual.Window([1920,1080])
>>> ts=visual.TextStim(win,'some text') 
>>> ts.height=.6
>>> ts.autoDraw=True
>>> win.flip()           ###Shows 'Some text' over two lines in .6 height
45.916739664040506
>>> ts.boundingBox
(794, 724)
>>> ts.height=.4
>>> win.flip()          ###shows 'some text' over one line in .4 height
81.28536250023171
>>> ts.boundingBox
(942, 241)
>>> ts.height=.6
>>> ts.text='some_text'
>>> win.flip()         ###shows 'some_text' in one line in .6 height
113.71247935923748
>>> ts.boundingBox
(1500, 362)
>>> ts.text='some text'
>>> win.flip()        ###shows 'some text' in two lines in .6 height
139.62244182173163
>>> ts.boundingBox
(794, 724)
>>>
```

**----> How do I expand the width of the bounding box so that text stays on one line?**

THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: Use wrapWidth.

```
ts.wrapWidth=2
```

resolved the issue